# How can I replace specified whitespaces in string?

Tags: java, android, string, replace, kotlin

I have a string:

```
2+3-{Some value}
```

How can I prevent user from adding spaces between operators and operands, but allow to add spaces between curly braces? Maybe regex?

**Update**

I'm working on real time validating formula. All validations including whitespace removal are done using `TextWatcher`. My simplified code looks like this:

```
private val formulaWatcher: TextWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) = Unit

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) = Unit

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            //Delay used here to avoid IndexOfBoundExceptions which arise because of a setSelection() method, it works with a little delay
            Handler().postDelayed({
                removeSpaces(s)
            }, 100)
        }
    }
```

Remove spaces function:

```
private fun removeSpaces(s: CharSequence) {
        if (s.last().isWhitespace()) {
            val textWithoutSpaces = s.replace(Regex("\\s"), "")
            getText().clear()
            append(textWithoutSpaces)
            setSelection(textWithoutSpaces.length)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. Show us a complete example, and the code you have, and tell us where it deviates from your expectations.

Comment: *Maybe regex?* - gooed idea using `String::replaceAll`

Comment: @ScaryWombat replaceAll will replace all whitespaces in string. I need to save spaces between curly braces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UDATE**

Based on that code snippet you provided, I modified the answer.
First, use trim() function to remove spaces from the beginning and end of the input string. After trimming the string, use the following regular expression to reach the desired pattern.

```
private fun removeSpaces(s: CharSequence) {
    // e.g. s is " 2 + 3 - { some value } " 
    s = s.trim()
    // now s is "2 + 3 - { some value }"

    // define a regex matching a pattern of characters including some spaces before and after an operator (+,-,*,/)
    val re = Regex("""\s*([\+\-\*\/])\s*""")

    // $1 denotes the group in the regex containing only an operator
    val textWithoutSpaces = re.replace(s, "$1")
    // textWithoutSpaces is "2+3-{ some value }"

    getText().clear()
    append(textWithoutSpaces)
    setSelection(textWithoutSpaces.length)
}
```

The regex works in this way that finds each operator i.e. `+`,`-`,`*`,and `/` along with white spaces before and after it. By grouping the operator itself using parantheses, all patterns including extra spaces are replaced by only the operators without any extra spaces.

Comment: thanks, but this not working. Because it's deleting spaces only from start and end. If we paste string like this: `2+ {oper 1}`, we will get: `2+ {oper 1}`

Comment: From your update and comments, I think you mean `2 + 3 - { any string }` must be converted to `2+3-{ any string }`. Am I right?

Comment: @Skullper I added a regex to the solution and tested it. It works fine.

Comment: @Abdolah Wow, thank you it really helps. I have tried regex with look-ahead, but your solution is more sophisticated)